# naming "id.jsx" instead of "[id].jsx" for dynamic routing with Next.js

Tags: next.js, amazon-cloudfront, serverless

I'm trying to serve my `next.js` with `AWS Lambda` as `serverless`.

and I've encountered trouble about dynamic routing.

My directory is like below that.

```
pages
 -courses
   -[id].jsx
   -index.jsx
 -index.jsx
```

It works well on my local server.

But on my Real server(`AWS Cloudfront`), it doesn't support dynamic routing.

The problem is about `courses/[id].jsx`.

When I entered my website, I can see an error message on the console.

> GET https://RANDOM.cloudfront.net/_next/static/RANDOM/pages/courses/[id].js net::ERR_ABORTED 400

So, I changed the name `[id].jsx` to `id.jsx` and I built and deploy it.

and it works.

But I'm not sure it is the correct way to solve my problem.

because `nextjs` says using `[]` with dynamic routing.

My question is that is my solution naming without `[]` is proper or no problem?

and If I am wrong how can I fix it?

Comment: which nextjs version you are using ? @zynkn

Comment: facing the same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: @KamilJanowski yes, What Next.js version are you using?

Comment: 9.4.4. The latest one

Comment: @KamilJanowski, As far as I know, this problem has been solved at `Next.js 9`